# Wrong naming convention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I've never used Unit Test before but only Rspec. So maybe here's some silly mistake.

I have `CountriesController`:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @country = Country.new(params[:country])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @country.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@country, :notice => 'Country was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @country, :status => :created, :location => @country }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @country.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and test `countries_controller_test.rb` for it :

```
class CountriesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  should_not_respond_to_actions :new => :get, :destroy => :get

  setup do
    @country = countries(:one)
  end

  test "should create country" do
    assert_difference('Country.count') do
      post :create, :country => @country.attributes.merge({ :code => Time.now.to_s })
    end

    assert_redirected_to country_path(assigns(:country))
  end
  ...
end
```

As far as I know the name convention, everything looks ok for me but I got an error:

```
1) Error:
test_should_create_country(CountriesControllerTest):
RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
```

What might be a problem here? Thanks

Comment: Please show the complete test file.

Comment: @RyanBigg, please follow link to see the full report https://gist.github.com/sevenmaxis/4758784

Comment: @megas Do you have an instance of `@controller` any where in the test file?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy, no, I don't have any '@controller' instance in my test file, I've updated my gist

Answer (score 0):

Where is the test's @controller supposed to come from ? If it's created by ActionController::TestCase, then you might want to call the superclass's setup in your own setup function ?